# Andorid Studio (Volley ) JsonObjectRequest

Tags: javascript, java, php

I tried everything to get data through a query with the JsonObjectRequest and it doesn't bring me any information, the query is well done, I just don't know why it doesn't bring me the data

```
public void ViewDate(View view){

    String get_id= ID.getText().toString().trim();
    String url="http://192.165.0.196/android_msyql/consultar.php?id"+get_id;
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,null,

            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    String nametxt, emailtxt;
                    try {

                        nametxt = (String) response.get("name");
                        emailtxt = (String) response.get("email");
                        nombre.setText(nametxt);
                        email.setText(emailtxt);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this," NOTHING",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

    );
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your test on local, try to check an ip address (on window open cmd run ipconfig) then put your ip address again.

This's an example

```
String url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/user"; //-- error
String url = "http://172.16.5.240:8080/user"; //-- worked
```